# Java Spring Data Elasticsearch query on date

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

I'm using Java Spring Data and I want to do a combined query that searches on a keyword and also checks the date of the object is newer than a given date. The search on keyword works but the search on date isn't. I'm not getting any errors either.

What the date mapping looks like in Elasticsearch:

[image: mapping elasticsearch]

In my Repository code in Java Spring I added this function:

```
List<Something> findByDescriptionAndDescriptionContainingAndPublishedDateGreaterThan(String description, String keyword, String date);
```

I add the String date in the same format as the date in Elasticsearch mapping. The result I get seems to just be ignoring the date, so I just get the same results as if I wouldn't be search with a 'greater than' date. I'm guessing I need to use something else than a String but I have no idea what.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why you don't using QueryBuilder?

Comment: Can you give some more info? Are you talking about NativeSearchQueryBuilder ?

Comment: I mean this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.3/query-dsl-queries.html , there is possible to build query, where you can define from and to and I thint there is able to use Date